# Why is this C# program which uses a "function" not working?

Tags: c#, function, c#-4.0, sharpdevelop

I've made a small C# program that takes an array with some numbers (float) inside and that tells how many numbers in the array are not in the interval ]a,b] 
I succeeded. Here is the program:

```
using System;

namespace Exercice_1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a = ?");
            float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("b = ?");
            float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            float[] t = new float[50];
            for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++)
            {
                 t[i]=4*i;
            }

            int k = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++)
            {
                if(t[i] <= a || t[i] > b)
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }

            Console.Write(""+k);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

But then I wanted to try making that same program but with using a "function".
But I did not succeed. Here is the program:

```
using System;

namespace Exercice_2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a = ?");
            float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("b = ?");
            float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            float[] t = new float[50];
            for(int i=0; i<t.Length; i++)
            {
                t[i]=4*i;
            }

            Console.Write(""+count(float[] t, float a, float b));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static int count(float[] u, float x, float y)
        {
            int k = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<u.Length; i++)
            {
                if(u[i] <= x || u[i] > y)
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }

            return k;
         }
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting the function outside "class Program", but it didn't work either.

It's the first time I'm trying to use a "function" so I probably made some obvious beginner mistakes...

Here are all the "errors" which SharpDevelop is pointing out:  http://oi62.tinypic.com/dnydsk.jpg

Comment: Don't specify types when calling the method, so your method call should be `Console.Write(""+count(t,a, b));`

Comment: All methods must be part of a class, the method should be **inside** the `Program` class.

Comment: It is inside the program class, the brackets just aren't lined up correctly

Comment: It's like looking at an Escher :O

Comment: Please post the errors here, not a link to a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.Write(""+count(float[] t, float a, float b));
```

Should be

```
Console.Write(""+count(t, a, b));
```

When calling a method, you do not need to specifiy the types, that is declared in the method signature

```
Signiture: count(float[] u, float x, float y)
To Call: count(t, a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
Console.Write(""+count(float[] t, float a, float b));
```

needs to be:

```
Console.Write(count(t, a, b));
```

When you call a function, you pass variables. The types are already fixed.